# Saving vector asset Output Directories is not ok

Tags: android-studio

When i want to save any `vector asset`, In `Output Directories` there is two res res forlder, when i want to save the image its make a new res forlder and save in it. But I want to save the image in drawable folder. here the image you can see the double res folder instead of `res->drawable-> image`.
and my case its showing `res -> res -> drawable -> image`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

please check  your sourceSets in gradle file, maybe you edited it out. 
Otherwise, I hope adding these lines to your gradle file will help you

```
   sourceSets{
   main {
    manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    java.srcDirs = ['src/commonFiles/java']
    resources.srcDirs = ['src/commonFiles/java']
    aidl.srcDirs = ['src/commonFiles/java']
    renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/commonFiles/java']
    res.srcDirs = ['res']
    assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
  }
  }
```

Comment: If you have multiple resource directories defined, it unfortunately shows only the last one, so it is probably best to place the main resource directory at the end of the list and move it from there if needed.